# How can I put join in 3 tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join, left-join

I am having three tables. Main table which I want to show contain all the data whereas the other two tables contain the values whose reference ID's are available in main table. I want to show all the values from main table along with the values whose references are available in other two tables.

PART_ID and SERIAL_ID values are available in Table B and Table C respectively. How can i show the data?

I am using inner join which shows result but not as per my requirement.

Here is my SQL code:

```
SELECT 
    TEMP_RMA_ENQUIRY.TEMP_ID, 
    PART_NUMBER_TBL.PART_NO, 
    PART_SERIAL.SERIAL_NUM 
FROM TEMP_RMA_ENQUIRY
INNER JOIN PART_NUMBER_TBL 
    ON TEMP_RMA_ENQUIRY.RMA_PART_NO=PART_NUMBER_TBL.PARTID
INNER JOIN PART_SERIAL 
    ON TEMP_RMA_ENQUIRY.RMA_SERIAL_NO=PART_SERIAL.SERIAL_ID
```

Comment: why is the result wrong? what are you expecting to get?

Comment: It might help if you told us what the "requirement" is.  If you want everything from `TEMP_RMA_ENQUIRY` and only those that match from `PART_NUMBER_TBL` and `PART_SERIAL` then use `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: I'm not clear on your requirement, nor in which way your example query fails to meet your requirement.  A helpful practice is to give us some sample data and then an example of the output you desire.  Using [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com) can be helpful for that.

Comment: Do you want to replace the INNER JOIN with LEFT JOINs?  Are you saying you want to show results from the main table even if there is no corresponding record in tables B and C?

Comment: Main table contains the ID's whose vales are available in other tables. I want to show all the records from main table but I want to use the VALUES from other two tables.

Comment: @AshishSharma For that you need to use Left JOIN Instead of Iner Join as bellow...

Answer (score 3):

> Use Left Join Instead of Inner JOIN

Try this

```
SELECT TEMP_RMA_ENQUIRY.TEMP_ID, 
       PART_NUMBER_TBL.PART_NO, 
       PART_SERIAL.SERIAL_NUM 
  FROM TEMP_RMA_ENQUIRY 
       LEFT JOIN PART_NUMBER_TBL 
                  ON TEMP_RMA_ENQUIRY.RMA_PART_NO=PART_NUMBER_TBL.PARTID 
       LEFT JOIN PART_SERIAL 
                  ON TEMP_RMA_ENQUIRY.RMA_SERIAL_NO=PART_SERIAL.SERIAL_ID
```